# Reference is able to refer to a different object (not in the iteration/loop body)

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

There are questions about this but seems regarding the iteration scenario.  I've got a different situation here. The reference definition and "re-assignment" happen in the same scope.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int obja = 10, objb = 20;
    int &r = obja;
    cout << r << endl; // prints the 10
    r = objb; // ???? re-assigning worked? 
    cout << r << endl; // prints the 20
    return 0;
}
```

**Question:**

What I've understood wrongly?

Comment: You aren't checking that values of `obja` and `objb`. The reference most certainly did not rebind.

Comment: `r = objb;` is the same as `obja = objb;` in this context.

Comment: @ ahh! I got it, it just copped the value of objb in to obja, but the r is still refers to obja

Comment: @SLN Well, kind of... But not quite as `r` **is** `obja`.

Comment: @Ron would be very nice of you to elaborate a bit on the the not quite part

Comment: Ron means that `r` and `obja` are two names for the same object. A reference is best thought of like that. Just another name. So to speak of `r` is to speak of `obja`.

Comment: @all you guys are awesome, Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reassigning a new value to `obja`, via `r`.
The new value happens to be the value of `objb`.
This does not reassociate the reference `r` to `objb`, I think you might be puzzled by what seems to be a demonstration of reassociating a reference to a new variable. That does not happen.
You can demonstrate what happens if you add at the end e.g.

```
cout << obja << " " << objb << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

`r = objb;` is not making **r** as a reference to **objb** , just value of **objb** is assigned to **r**.
 Try to print the address of both **r** and **objb**, it will have different address.

```
cout <<"address of r = "<<&r<<endl;
cout <<"address of objb = "<<&objb<<endl;
```

If it was **reference** it prints same address like in `int &r = obja;` because **r** is reference of **obja**  both are having the same address.